# load time series from csv

Tags: r, csv, time-series

I want to load time series data from a csv file. I am confused if it is possible using the `ts()` function?

The data looks like this:

```
time(ms),value
1390933817000,3775.89624023438
1390933847000,3765.65698242188
1390933877000,3757.01416015625
1390933907000,3768.63623046875
1390933937000,3775.84497070312
1390933967000,3774.53588867188
1390933997000,3771.6240234375
1390934027000,3763.83081054688
```

As you can observe, the value is fetched every 30 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (noting comment):

```
Lines <- "time(ms),value
1390933817000,3775.89624023438
1390933847000,3765.65698242188
1390933877000,3757.01416015625
1390933907000,3768.63623046875
1390933937000,3775.84497070312
1390933967000,3774.53588867188
1390933997000,3771.6240234375
1390934027000,3763.83081054688"

library(zoo)
# z <- read.zoo("myfile.dat", sep = ",", header = TRUE, FUN = identity)
z <- read.zoo(text = Lines, sep = ",", header = TRUE, FUN = identity)
as.ts(z)
```

Comment: It seems the zoo library will be useful. Could you please tell what does FUN = identity mean?

Comment: `FUN` specifies a function to apply to the time index.  In this case we don't want to make any change to it so we apply the identity function.  (The default is `"POSIXct"` or '"Date"` depending on whether or not `tz=` is specified.) See `?read.zoo` for more information.  Also there is an entire vignette (i.e. pdf document) in zoo about read.zoo, `vignette("zoo-read")`